# Why do we use "theory" to describe both untested models and models corroborated beyond reasonable doubt?

Tags: terminology

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_theory) says:

> A scientific theory is an explanation of an aspect of the natural world and universe that has been repeatedly tested and verified in accordance with the scientific method, using accepted protocols of observation, measurement, and evaluation of results.

Theories are typically corroborated beyond reasonable doubt, good examples being atomic theory, the kinetic theory of gases, and the theory of relativity. Why, then, do physicists use the word "theory" to describe models we can't even test yet, like string theory? Is it just because the more general definition of "theory" is more along the lines of speculation?

Comment: Note the adjective Wikipedia's chosen to add  There's a difference between "a scientific(ally successful) theory" in Wikipedia's sense & theories scientists pun-not-intended experiment with.

Comment: The meaning of a word can change in different contexts. The meaning of a word is the use to which it is put. This is not a physics question. This question should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

It's still correct to call it a theory.

A theory can explain nature without making testable predictions that differentiate it from other theories, as long as it makes testable predictions at all. Most such can be dismissed as non-falsifiable variations on more elegant theories. E.g. "Relativity but with harder math and it's because of undetectable fairies." Some, e.g. String Theory, look like they'll probably be falsifiable someday if we follow the math far enough, and can't be dismissed as long as its predictions comport with data, even if it would be possible to make those same predictions with better established theories.